How to enable a webcam on an LXD virtual machine
I have a virtual machine running Windows 10 on an LXD container. I recently enabled audio on this VM with the following instructions:
lxc config set win10 raw.qemu -- "-device intel-hda -device hda-duplex"\
lxc config set win10 raw.qemu -- "-device intel-hda -device hda-duplex -audio spice"

Now I need to enable a webcam. I tried the following:
lxc config device add win10 logcam usb vendor_id=046d product_id=080a

based on the lsusb output:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub\
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:20cf Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen\
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface\
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:080a Logitech, Inc. Portable Webcam C905\
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:0379 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Truevision HD\
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

but I got this error message:
Device validation failed for "logcam": Invalid device option "product_id"

Either Logitech or Cheng Uei webcams works for me, but I'd really appreciate if you can help me with both.
